# parallel evolution along a lake-stream environmental contrast

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Speciation dynamics and extent of **parallel evolution along a lake-stream environmental contrast** in African cichlid fishes

> Source: [Science](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abg5391)

What is the definition for the word "along" here? It seems to mean "in the context of" in some way. I am not sure. What does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article uses the preposition *along* 28 different times, with several different objects:

a lake-stream environmental contrast
the speciation continuum
similar environmental contrasts
an environmental contrast across different temporal and geographic scales.
a continuum of genomic differentiation
a common axis of morphological differentiation
a given linkage group
a depth gradient in Lake Victoria
a benthic-limnetic axis of Midas cichlids

They are describing how a dependent variable changes with an independent variable, while describing the change of the independent variable as movement **along** a continuum.

For a simple, concrete example, suppose y = x^2, and we want to describe how y changes as x changes from 0 to 5. We might say "Y changes from zero to 25 **along** the change in x from 0 to 5".